# Testing a query parameter in django restframework

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I am testing a query parameter in djnago restframework to retrieve the detail of an object.  The query works in the browser but not the test.  I think  I am not calling the response correctly with:

```
    response = self.client.get(reverse('quote-requests:get-calculator-detail', kwargs={'calculator_code': self.calc1.calculator_code}))
```

the apps urls.py

```
       
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('api/v1/quote-requests/', include('quote_requests.urls')),
    ]
```

which includes the quotes.urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path, include
    from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

    from quote_requests import views 

    router = DefaultRouter()
    router.register('get-calculator', views.CalculatorCodeDetailViewSet, basename='get-calculator')

    app_name = 'quote-requests'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

The viewset is:

```
    class CalculatorCodeDetailViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

        serializer_class        = CalculatorCodeSerializer

        lookup_field            = ('calculator_code')
        
        def get_queryset(self):
            return (
                Calculator.objects.filter(
                    calculator_code = self.request.query_params.get('calculator_code',)
                    )
            )
```

The CalculatorCodeSerializer is:

```
    class CalculatorCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


        class Meta:
            model = Calculator
            fields = (
                'name',
                'calculator_code',
                )
```

The test  is:

```
    def test_retrieving_calculator_detail_with_calculator_code(self):
            ''' test retrieving detail of a calculator '''
            self.calc1 = Calculator.objects.create(
                name                =  "Calculator 1000",
                calculator_code     = "HH1000",
            )

            response = self.client.get(reverse('quote-requests:get-calculator-detail', kwargs={'calculator_code': self.calc1.calculator_code}))

            serializer = CalculatorCodeSerializer(self.calc1)

            self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
```

This yields the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/app/quote_requests/tests/test_calculators_api.py", line 149, in test_retrieving_calculator_detail_with_calculator_code
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
    AssertionError: {'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Not found.',[14 chars]nd')} != {'name': 'Calculator 1000', 'calculator_cod[368 chars].25'}
```

When checking the browser link:

```
    http://localhost:8000/api/v1/quote-requests/get-calculator/?calculator_code=HH1000
```

This works but test fails.  Any help setting up the properly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong endpoint name replace this "get-calculator-detail" with this "get-calculator"

`def test_retrieving_calculator_detail_with_calculator_code(self):
# test retrieving detail of a calculator
self.calc1 = Calculator.objects.create(
name                =  "Calculator 1000",
calculator_code     = "HH1000",
)
response = self.client.get(reverse('quote-requests:get-
calculator', kwargs={'calculator_code':
self.calc1.calculator_code}))
serializer = CalculatorCodeSerializer(self.calc1)
self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not the issue or  creates another issue of raising a " raise NoReverseMatch(msg)" ... I believe because the model view  ReadOnlyModelViewSet's magic makes -detail required on the reverse method

Answer (score 0):

With the help of others on Fiverr  I have gotten the test to pass.  I hesitate to call it answered but  I am putting the detail here in case those who know a better way  can comment.

TLDR - the  response variable was not written correctly either the reverse does not do what I want or it cannot be done with  reverse.  Either way the change that worked was:

`response = self.client.get('/api/v1/quote-requests/get-calculator/',  {'calculator_code': self.calc1.calculator_code})`

This does not return an iterable object.  It returns an OrderDict which looks like this:

`[{"name":"Calculator 1000","calculator_code":"HH1000","id":7,}]`

I used print(response.content) to check this.

so you need to use the json function to pull the  data out and match it to serializer.data - the response from the serializer.

`response.data = response.json()[0]`

this pulls the "[]" off and formats it like this:

`{'name': 'Calculator 1000', 'calculator_code': 'HH1000', 'id': 7, }`

The [0] on the  end gets the object (I think) and returns it in json format.

The two fiverr users that  helped me with this were:
https://www.fiverr.com/tailongk
and
https://www.fiverr.com/asipita